# adding new column to a pandas dataframe based on another dataframe column with different rows number

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, geojson

I'm new on Python applied to DataScience and I'm a bit stuck on a (simple) problem...

I have 2 data frames: data (stores last Madrid's election results) and map_municipios (stores data of Madrid's municipalities as GeoJSON).

I would like to represent a map with election results. I could achieve it, but as I couldn't to put proper geographical info from map_municipios in data dataframe, municipalities names and info are not OK (i.e. Madrid municipality shows another name and results).

My two data frames have the following info:

```
data.info()

 #   Column                      Non-Null Count  Dtype  
 ---  ------                      --------------  -----  
 0   cpro                        179 non-null    int64  
 1   cmun                        179 non-null    int64  
 2   municipio                   179 non-null    object 
 ......

 map_municipios.info()

 16  cpro         164 non-null    object  
 17  cmun         164 non-null    object  
 18  dc           164 non-null    object  
 19  codigo_post  164 non-null    object  
 20  geometry     182 non-null    geometry
```

All my project info is on these links:
[MadridElections](https://github.com/BernardoJoseLlamasVerna/Madrid_Elections_2021/blob/main/Madrid_Elections_2021.ipynb) [Full Repo](https://github.com/BernardoJoseLlamasVerna/Madrid_Elections_2021)

Well I'm trying that info between both dataframes fix properly using the following columns: 'cpro' and 'cmun'. If cpro and cmun are equal in both dataframes, 'geometry' column value has to be added to new 'geometry' column in data dataframe.

Searching info I tried the following:

```
data['geometry'] = np.where(
  (data['cpro'].equals(map_municipios['cpro'])) & 
  (data['cmun'].equals(map_municipios['cmun'])), 
   map_municipios['geometry'], 0
)
```

It returns an error because len(data)!=len(map_municipios) (179!=182). len(data) is the correct number os municipalities of Madrid region.

I tried using pd.Series before np.where(...), but it creates the data['geometry'] column fulfilled of zeroes instead coordinates values.

QUESTION: is there any easy way to get my map_municipios['geometry'] column and give it to data dataframe in correct order (despite of having len different values, extra values would be dismissed).

Any hint, link, etc will be really appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think what you looking for is a `join` operation, checkout [pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html#database-style-dataframe-or-named-series-joining-merging)

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer...I've been trying but didn't succeed yet

I don't know why doing result = pd.merge(data, map_municipios, how='left', on=["cpro", "cmun"]) doesn't represent my data on geojson map (last image on my notebook). 

Doing result = pd.merge(data, map_municipios, left_index=True , right_index=True, how='inner') can be represented, but coordinates are still not ok so merge is not being doing fine using the columns 'cpro' and 'cmun'...Would you know what is wrong?

I will be trying a bit more to figure out what's wrong...any more help will be appreciated ;) Thnk

Answer (score 4):

This seems like a problem for an inner join. The inner join in pandas allows you to join according to one or more values in two data frames. You can read this for more info and examples: [inner join](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2020/02/joins-in-pandas-master-the-different-types-of-joins-in-python/)

According to your problem, It seems you might also need to select the specific columns you want to merge to from the map_municipios dataframe. This should achieve what you want :

```
data = data.merge(map_municipios[['cpro', 'cmun', 'geometry']], on=['cpro', 'cmun'], how='inner').
```

This way you just select the specific columns and your desired 'geometry' column and merge them on the two columns cpro and cmun. Let me know if this solves your issue.

Below is a more detailed solution to your problem:

```
# %%
import pandas as pd

# %%
data = pd.read_csv('Elecciones_Madrid_2021_Municipios.csv', delimiter=';', thousands='.', decimal=',')

# %%
data = data.rename(columns={"Codcir":"cpro", "Codmun":"cmun", "Municipio":"municipio"})

# %%
data.head()

# %%
import geopandas as gpd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# %%
municipios = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/FMullor/TopoJson/master/MadridMunicipios.geojson'
map_municipios = gpd.read_file(municipios)
map_municipios = map_municipios.sort_values('municipio')
map_municipios.head(30)

# %%
map_municipios['cmun'] = pd.to_numeric(map_municipios['cmun'])
map_municipios['cpro'] = pd.to_numeric(map_municipios['cpro'])

# %%
map_municipios.info()

# %%
data = data.merge(map_municipios[['cpro', 'cmun', 'geometry']], on=['cpro', 'cmun'], how='inner')

# %%
data.head()
    

cpro    cmun    municipio   Unnamed: 3  Censo   Certif. Alta    Censo Total Votos Totales   Votos Blancos   Votos Nulos ... VOLT    VOX P-LIB   POLE    MÁS MADRID  EB  UDEC    PODEMOS-IU  RECORTES CERO-PCAS-TC-GV-M  geometry
0   28  2   Ajalvir NaN 3251    0   3251    2339    10  15  ... 0   340 1   0   330 1   1   101 0   MULTIPOLYGON (((-3.51150 40.53889, -3.50521 40...
1   28  3   Alameda del Valle   NaN 195 0   195 168 3   0   ... 0   16  0   0   36  0   0   11  0   MULTIPOLYGON (((-3.80596 40.89047, -3.80951 40...
2   28  5   Alcalá de Henares   NaN 136163  4   136167  100932  603 789 ... 45  9735    21  10  15540   70  26  7017    29  MULTIPOLYGON (((-3.32142 40.47207, -3.32898 40...
3   28  6   Alcobendas  NaN 80401   2   80403   62036   297 363 ... 36  5533    24  8   8212    60  44  3430    26  MULTIPOLYGON (((-3.67417 40.58897, -3.65981 40...
4   28  7   Alcorcón    NaN 126919  0   126919  97563   565 769 ... 35  7841    14  4   16945   128 24  7707    66  MULTIPOLYGON (((-3.78781 40.35875, -3.79893 40.
```

Comment: Please use provided input data and display your output to validate your answer.

Comment: Thanks, I have used the inputs and got the merged output as required.